# MVVM: class that implements ViewModel not updating its Model instance

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

So I've been trying to implement the `MVVM` pattern within a simple `WPF` application that has the following structure:

**MODEL**

```
public class Foobar
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }

    public string DoSomethingWithFoo()
    {
        return "The quick brown fox";
    }

    public string DoSomethingWithBar()
    {
        return "jumps over the lazy dog.";
    }
}
```

**VIEW MODEL (BASE)**

```
public abstract class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    [Conditional("DEBUG")]
    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public void VerifyPropertyName(string propertyName)
    {
        if (TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this)[propertyName] == null)
        {
            Debug.Fail("Invalid property name: " + propertyName);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        this.VerifyPropertyName(propertyName);

        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

**VIEW MODEL (IMPL)**

```
public class FoobarViewModel : ViewModel
{
    private readonly Foobar foobar;

    public string Foo
    {
        get
        {
            return this.foobar.Foo;
        }
        set
        {
            this.foobar.Foo = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Foo");
        }
    }

    public string Bar
    {
        get
        {
            return this.foobar.Bar;
        }
        set
        {
            this.foobar.Bar = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Bar");
        }
    }

    private FoobarCommand fooCommand;
    public FoobarCommand FooCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return fooCommand;
        }
        set
        { 
            fooCommand = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("FooCommand");
        }
    }

    private FoobarCommand barCommand;
    public FoobarCommand BarCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return barCommand;
        }
        set
        { 
            barCommand = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("BarCommand");
        }
    }

    private void DoSomethingWithFoo()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.foobar.Foo))
        {
            this.foobar.Foo = this.foobar.DoSomethingWithFoo();
            OnPropertyChanged("Foo");
        }
    }

    private void DoSomethingWithBar()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.foobar.Bar))
        {
            this.foobar.Bar = this.foobar.DoSomethingWithBar();
            OnPropertyChanged("Bar");
        }
    }

    ///<remarks>
    /// must use the parameterless constructor to satisfy <Window.Resources>
    ///</remarks>
    public FoobarViewModel()
    {
        this.foobar = new Foobar()
        {
            Foo = "Lorem",
            Bar = "Ipsum"
        }

        this.fooCommand = new FoobarCommand(DoSomethingWithFoo);
        this.barCommand = new FoobarCommand(DoSomethingWithBar);
    };
}
```

**COMMAND**

```
public class FoobarCommand : ICommand
{
    Action action;

    public FoobarCommand(Action action)
    {
        this.action = action;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        this.action.Invoke();
    }
}
```

**VIEW**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:FoobarViewModel x:Key="FoobarViewModel" />
</Window.Resources>

<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource FoobarViewModel}">

    <TextBox Name="FooTextBox" Text="{Binding Foo, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
    <TextBox Name="BarTextBox" Text="{Binding Bar, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />

</Grid>
```

The problem with this approach is, despite that the `ViewModel` is binding okay with the `View`, the `Model` is not reflecting such changes (meaning the `Model` is not *notifying-back* changes to its instance at the `ViewModel`)

I would really appreciate any bit of advice regarding this post, thanks much you guys in advance.

**EDIT**

1. Updated snippets with the missing code (thanks Pavlo and Ben)
2. Committed solution to a public svn repo http://nanotaboada.svn.beanstalkapp.com/dotnet/trunk/Dotnet.Samples.Rijndael/ for anyone interested in checking out the whole project.
3. Modified `Model` and `ViewModel` methods, added `ICommand` implementation. For a full working sample please checkout revision 16.

Comment: What have you tried? Set a breakpoint on the VM setters? Are they being called?

Comment: How do you know "the model is reflecting such changes"  For that matter how do you know the "ViewModel is binding ok with the view"  Where are you setting the datacontext to your foobarviewmodel instance?

Comment: @Kent: they're being called indeed.
@Ralph: I know the model is reflecting such changes because such model has an internal method that uses its properties to do some computation.

Thank both of you guys for your contributions!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything looks OK except one small, but important detail. It looks like you forgot to set `DataContext` of your view to the instance of the view model.

```
<Window ...
        DataContext="{StaticResource FoobarViewModel}">
```

Without it your bindings will fail (look in the output window of Visual Studio when under debugger and you'll see binding errors).

Also note that the values will be updated in your view model and model when the `TextBox` looses focus. To make it update while you type set `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `PropertyChanged` on your bindings:

```
<TextBox Name="FooTextBox" Text="{Binding Foo, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Comment: @Pavlo: Thanks for the heads up -- I've indeed forgotten to put that in this code sample but actually it's there (I mean in the real app), so currently the binding **from** the `View` **to** the `ViewModel` _works_, the thing that doesn't work is notifications/updates **from** the `Model` **to** the `ViewModel`. Don't hesitate to let me know if I should elaborate more on any details.

Comment: @Pavlo: regarding `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` I believe it's the default for most dependency properties, including `<TextBox.Text>` so I guess in principle that wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @Nano - No, default usually is `LostFocus`. At least for `TextBox.Text` it is for sure `LostFocus`.

Comment: @Pavlo: Added `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` but nothing changed.

Comment: @Nano - Did you set `DataContext` as I showed in the beginning of my answer? If no, do so. if yes, run you application under the debugger and set breakpoints in the setters of the properties in your view model. Are the setters getting called? If no, look in the Output window in Visual Studio - there should be binding errors.

Comment: @Pavlo: setters are indeed being called and working, the problem is, the `Model` properties are not _notifying-back_ its changes to the `ViewModel` properties. I maintain that should not be neccessary to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the `Model` because that's actually one of the reasons for having a `ViewModel` abstraction.

Comment: @Nano - You still need to notify the view model when you change `Foo` in the `DoSomethingWithFoo` method. Having a view model alone doesn't mean that it will magically know about all the changes in the model... So, you need to fire some event in your model to which the view model will subscribe and in turn fire the `PropertyChanged` event to notify the view that something has changed.

Comment: @Pavlo: thanks for the tip, I understand what you mean, I'm going to try to reimplement `DoSomethingWithFoo` so it doesn't update `Foo` from within (I'd probably make it return a string instead of void).

Answer (score 1):

In your FooBarViewModel you are not instantiating your Model, it is left as null, since you marked it readonly, you will need to **new** it in a default constructor.

Comment: that's also true, I've forgotten to put the default constructor in the code sample (I'll be updating it asap) by now let's assume it's there. Thanks for the comment though.